# check whether the number is nearly equal javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know whether it is possible?

Let Suppose:

```
var a = 2592;
var b = 2584;
if(a nearly equal to b) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: nearly equal in what range?

Comment: hey i know that formula but chrome says ABS is not defined.! :(

Comment: Weird I'm  using chrome now and it works fine in the console, are you writing Math.ABS maybe?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like so.

```
var diff = Math.abs( a - b );

if( diff > 50 ) {
    console.log('diff greater than 50');
}
```

That would compare if the absolute difference is greater than `50` using `Math.abs` and simple comparison.

Comment: thanks just was not using Math. with abs ;) thanks this helped i knew the formula but i think brain fart. +1 and will accept answer after 11 minutes. Salute Sir!

Answer (score 19):

Here's the old school way to do it...

```
approxeq = function(v1, v2, epsilon) {
  if (epsilon == null) {
    epsilon = 0.001;
  }
  return Math.abs(v1 - v2) < epsilon;
};
```

so,

```
approxeq(5,5.000001)
```

is true, while

```
approxeq(5,5.1)
```

is false.

You can adjust pass in epsilons explicitly to suit your needs. One part in a thousand usually covers my javascript roundoff issues.

Comment: This was very handy to compare floating points numbers comparatively to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

One line Es6 way version of [The Software Barbarian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680799/3030547):

```js
const approxeq = (v1, v2, epsilon = 0.001) => Math.abs(v1 - v2) <= epsilon;

console.log(approxeq(3.33333, 3.33322)); // true
console.log(approxeq(2.3, 2.33322)); // false
console.log(approxeq(3, 4, 1)); // true
```

I changed it to include the number in the margin. So with an epsilon margin of 1 `approxeq` between 1 and 2 is `true`

Comment: There is something aesthetically pleasing about => and <= in the same line. Lots of bonus points if you can figure out how to make it a palindrome.

Comment: This is completely dumb but:
`(epsilon) => Math.abs(epsilon.v1 - epsilon.v2) <= (epsilon.epsilon);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var ratio = 0;
if ( a > b) {
   ratio = b / a;
}
else {
    ratio = a / b;
}
if (ratio > 0.90) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The shorter way: `ratio = Math.min(a, b) / Max.max(b, a)`.

Comment: Shorter as in number of lines, I hope you say ;)

Comment: This breaks if a or b is zero. Also, simple addition/subtraction tends to be less expensive than division.

Comment: For floating point error, division is safer than subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point comparison gets complicated in a hurry. It's not as simple as diff less than epsilon in a lot of cases.

Here's an article about the subject, though not javascript specific.

https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

TLDR:

1. When one of the numbers being compared is very close to zero, subtracting the smaller from the larger can lose digits of precision, making the diff appear smaller than it is (or zero).
2. Very small numbers with different signs work in a weird way.
3. Dividing by zero will cause problems.

In the article is a function (java) which solves better for these cases:

```
public static boolean nearlyEqual(float a, float b, float epsilon) {
    final float absA = Math.abs(a);
    final float absB = Math.abs(b);
    final float diff = Math.abs(a - b);

    if (a == b) { // shortcut, handles infinities
            return true;
    } else if (a == 0 || b == 0 || (absA + absB < Float.MIN_NORMAL)) {
            // a or b is zero or both are extremely close to it
            // relative error is less meaningful here
            return diff < (epsilon * Float.MIN_NORMAL);
    } else { // use relative error
            return diff / Math.min((absA + absB), Float.MAX_VALUE) < epsilon;
    }
}
```

Before you complain: Yes, that's Java, so you'd have to rewrite it in Javascript. It's just to illustrate the algorithm and it's just copied from the article.

<s>I'm still looking for a thorough solution to this problem, ideally with an NPM package so I don't have to figure this out again every time I need it.</s>

Edit: I've found a package which implements the solution from the article linked above (which has the same link in their readme).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@intocode-io/nearly-equal

This will be a less error-prone solution than others shown in other answers. There are several npm packages which implement the naive solutions which have error cases near zero as described above. Make sure you look at the source before you use them.

Comment: I believe nearly-equal also has issues near 0: it uses a subnormal float, the lowest possible one, rather than MIN_NORMAL

Comment: I don't know for sure if nearly-equal has issues or not, but at the time I wrote this answer, out of all the packages I studied, nearly-equal did the most thorough treatment of floating-point quirks. The vast majority just did something like `Math.abs(difference) < EPSILON` and didn't consider anything else.

Comment: The line you're referring to is this one:
https://github.com/micksatana/nearly-equal/blob/master/src/nearly-equal.ts#L8
This code uses `Number.MIN_VALUE`, which is not the same as Java's `Float.MIN_NORMAL`. It seems this could be an issue.